# How to use squid regex acl to exclude a specific subdomain?

Tags: regex, regex-negation, squid

I want to block a domain but except a specific subdomain.

For example, I use `test.domain.com` as my production environment and deny all access from squid.
But I want allow squid user to access `test.demo.domain.com` which is a testing environment.

my squid.conf:

```
acl denylist dstdom_regex ^(?!.*(demo)).*domain\.com$
http_access deny denylist
http_access allow all
```

I know what's wrong with my regex. Squid regex use GNU regex (see [serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1095083/squid-regex-syntax-description)) and GNU regex can not understand `(?!.*(demo))`.

So how to exclude a specific subdomain in GNU regex?

Answer (score 1):

**There's no need for regex in your case!**

You said you need to allow only one specific subdomain. So add this subdomain in a ACL and allow access to it.

```
acl allowed_subdomain dstdomain test.demo.example.com
acl blocked_domain dstdomain .example.com


http_access allow allowed_subdomain
http_access deny blocked_domain
http_access deny all
```

**Explanation:**
Squid will read the config file looking for a match and the first one it encounters it ends it's job.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use negative lookbehind (`?<!`) instead of negative lookahead (`?!`). Second, I don't think it can work with `^` as it matches from the beginning of the domain. Third, with `.*domain.com` it will match
the whole domain anyway, so you should use `\.domain.com` instead.

The correct regex that doesn't match demo **anywhere** **before** `.domain.com` would be

```
(?<!(.*demo.*))\.domain\.com
```

Here, the domain must end with `.domain.com` and must not contain `demo` anywhere beforehand in order to match.